# has no installation candidate with all packages

Tags: debian, kali-linux

I have been trying to install many packages, Google Chrome and Monodevelop. But I run into the same problem everytime:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libappindicator1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libappindicator1' has no installation candidate
```

This happens with all packages. I have preformed the command `sudo apt-get -f install`, `apt-get update` and `apt-get update && apt-cache search kali-linux` successfully
 but it still does not work. (I am running Kali amd64). There is probably a really easy solution and I am just bad at googling stuff....

Sources.list:

```
@linux:~/Downloads$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2016.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160120-18:14]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2016.1 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20160120-18:14]/ kali-rolling contrib main non-free
```

Comment: What does the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file contain?

Comment: updated question @cherdt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your `sources.list` by adding the following line:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Run:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Reboot ; open the terminal and run the following commands :

```
apt-get install libappindicator1
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
apt-get -f install
```

Install `monodevelop` :

```
apt-get install  monodevelop
```